# Cannot resolve method 'getJSModule' in Android

Tags: java, android, react-native, import

I am using this method in android but it's displaying this error " **context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("Heartbeat",null);**"

I am importing `import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;` but still the problem remains. 
Any idea why it displays that? Couldn't find anything on the internet.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("Heartbeat",null);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not big on React, but I think you need the `ReactContext` as opposed to the Android application's `Context`. You are using the Android context which does not have the `getJSModule()` method.

Try

```
ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager();
// This is the context you need.
ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();
```

But I think you need your activity to extend `ReactActivity`.

Comment: where is getJSModule() now?

Comment: getReactNativeHost() is also not available in the service.